# API: Post,PUT and Delete returns 200k but no data inserted,updated or deleted

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to create a `restfull` API and I'm getting the data when I do a `GET` and `GetWithId` but when I `POST` `PUT` `DELETE` I get 200k as result and nothing happens data is not saved in `database` I've `debugged` every step of `POST` `PUT` `DELETE` but nothing is wrong `DATA` goes fine. Even the `context.SaveChanges()` does not throw any exception as I can see through debugging that  data is there and that is why there is no exception then what is that I could be doing wrong  and It also returns `0` 
   [image]

**Update**

for GET method which works perfectly

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

POST /api/product HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4914

```
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 695496c9-e950-d15f-661f-65bb37064903

{
  "id": 12,
  "productName": "sample string 2"
}
```

**Update 3**

This is my Delete Controller method

```
 public bool Delete(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            if (id > 0)
            {
                return _productServices.DeleteProduct(id);
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

This here is my Delete service method

```
 public bool DeleteProduct(int productId)
    {
        var success = false;
        if (productId > 0)
        {
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                var product = _unitOfWork.ProductRepository.GetById(productId);
                if (product != null)
                {
                    _unitOfWork.ProductRepository.Delete(product);
                    _unitOfWork.Save();
                    scope.Complete();
                    success = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return success;
    }
and here is my Generic Delete method 
        public virtual void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete)
    {
        if (Context.Entry(entityToDelete).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            DbSet.Attach(entityToDelete);
        }
        DbSet.Remove(entityToDelete);
    }
```

Comment: check your connection string

Comment: @NazmulHasan as I said dear I can see the data when I call the `GET` method please see the screen shot of in the update section

Comment: how you set you primary key ?  i mean auto increment or pass by id

Comment: I'm using auto increment

Comment: I think you table is locked by someone

Comment: @NazmulHasan can you be more specific?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112111/discussion-between-nazmul-hasan-and-user3515453).

Comment: show me you api controller crud operation code

Comment: Okay Please wait let me update the question

Comment: @NazmulHasan please have a look now

Comment: int num =  _unitOfWork.Save();  in the debug check number of row effected or not

Comment: That is zero most probably because I've used `SQL profiler` and nothing happens in it

Comment: @NazmulHasan Here is the problem I think [screen](http://prntscr.com/b52fni)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the bloody issue I wasn't creating the Unit Of Work `Constructor` parameter less when I created it parameter less it started working

```
     public UnitOfWork()
    {
        _context= new TheWorkEntities();
    }
```

**CAN ANY ONE guide WHY IS IT THAT WAY **